# when i click imagebutton the image change. Can i save this change when i return again in this activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, onsaveinstancestate

class suspect : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_suspect)
    imagebutton.setOnClickListener {
        imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture2)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could save an image identifier to [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) and then retrieve an image number from Shared Preferences when you open your activity. Then you use that number to set the ImageButton image.

I haven't ran this code, but something along the lines of this should work:

```
private val picture1Id = 1
private val picture2Id = 2
private val IMAGE_KEY = "IMAGE_KEY"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_suspect)

    imagebutton.setOnClickListener {
        saveImageIdentifier(picture2Id)
        imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture2)
    }
    
    setupImageButtonFromPreferences()
}

private fun saveImageIdentifier(id: Int) {
    val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
    with (sharedPref.edit()) {
        putInt(IMAGE_KEY, id)
        apply()
    }
}

private fun getImageIdentifier(): Int {
    val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return 1
    return sharedPref.getInt(IMAGE_KEY, 1)
}

private fun setupImageButtonFromPreferences() {
    when (getImageIdentifier()) {
        picture1Id -> imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture1)
        picture2Id -> imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture2)
        else -> return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 0

class suspect : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_suspect)

        if (a == 1){imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture2)}
        imagebutton.setOnClickListener {
            imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture2)
            a = 1
        }
        imagebutton.setOnLongClickListener {
            imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture1)
            a = 0
            true
        }
    }
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putInt("image", a)
    }
    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        a = savedInstanceState.getInt("image")
    }
}
```